# how to create virtual host in apache ubuntu 12.04 for node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, apache, ubuntu

I'm basically php developer and going to start work with node.js. And I've installed node.js with my ubuntu 12.04. After that I've tested http(http.js) is working fine. Here I need to know how create the virtual host like http://192.168.1.1:5001 with my system and specific route file(like index.php) with apache server. I've referred many links and not get good solution for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the virtual host set up for ubuntu 14.0 and angular and node:

Step: 1 -

Open 'hosts' file from '/etc'

Step: 2 -

Add below line at the last

```
127.0.0.1       abc.localhost
```

Step: 3 -

Open 'httpd-vhosts.conf' file from '/opt/lampp/etc/extra'

Step: 4 -

Add below code at the last

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName abc.localhost
  ServerAlias abc.localhost.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/    
</VirtualHost>
```

Step: 5 -

Restart the lampp server from terminal like typing sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
And enter to restart

Step: 6 -

Go to the directory where the node project set up in exists like typing cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/nodeProject on terminal and enter to start node server

Step: 7 -

Open browser and hit http://abc.localhost

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can create virtual host for apache and then use ProxyPass to forward the request to node server.

```
<VirtualHost node.example.com:80>   
    ServerName node.example.com  
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30  #    optional timeout settings  
</VirtualHost>
```

like this where node server is listening to the port no. 8000

Comment: Hi Nishant, Thanks for answer. I need to know above need to place httpd.conf file right or else need to it. And also know that while running executing this virtual host while need to be index file

Comment: i didn't get you... if you're asking for how to create virtual host.. then this link might help you.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: I'm not asked how create the virtual host in ubuntu. I'm asking that how to configure node.js application with virtual host with index file as like php. And as you said above answer I did it but i'm getting error like 503 service temporary unavailable